# Capillary rise for a tube with a glass rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, surface-tension

**Take a capillary tube (glass) of diameter $d_2$ dipped in water vertically. Now a glass rod with diameter $d_1$ is inserted in the tube. Find the height to which the water rises. Take contact angle to be 0.**

---

Now, one approach to this problem is equating the force due to the surface tension to the weight of the liquid column that rises in the capillary tube.$$T\pi (d_2 + d_1) = \frac{h\rho g\pi ({d_2}^2 - {d_1}^2)}{4} $$
Which gives,
$$h=\frac {4T}{(d_2 - d_1)\rho g} $$

Where $\rho$ is the density of water and $T $ is the surface tension.

---

The second approach could be using excess pressure due to the meniscus.

The radius of curvature of the meniscus formed will be $r = \frac {d_2 - d_1}{4}$

Hence,

$$h\rho g=\frac {2T}{r} $$

Which gives,

$$h=\frac {8T}{(d_2 - d_1)\rho g} $$

---

I am not sure which one of the answers is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find excess pressure balance the force due to excess pressure with force due to surface tension .($R=d2/2 \  ,  \ r=d1/2$)

$ΔP \timesπ(R^2-r^2)=2π(R+r)T$

$ΔP=2T/(R-r)$

Then if you equate it with weight you will get the same answer as 1. You have erroneously used the excess pressure formula which has been derived considering a spherical surface on a ring shaped surface.

You could also use the [young Laplace equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%E2%80%93Laplace_equation) for excess pressure,

$ΔP = T(1/R_1 + 1/R_2)$ where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are the maximum and minimum radius of curvature of any surface in gas liquid equilibrium.

For the given surface $R_1 = R_2 = (R-r)/2$